# EF DbContext incosistency

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following class:

```
public class ATMClient
{
    private ATMDbContext dbContext;
    private IOutputProvider outputProvider;

    public ATMClient(ATMDbContext dbContext)
        : this(dbContext, new ConsoleOutputProvider())
    {
    }

    public ATMClient(ATMDbContext dbContext, IOutputProvider outputProvider)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.outputProvider = outputProvider;
    }

    public void WithdrawMoney(string cardNumber, string cardPIN, decimal money)
    {
        using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
        {
            var currentAccount = dbContext.CardAccounts.Where(x => x.CardNumber == cardNumber).FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                currentAccount.CardCash -= money;

                throw new ArgumentException("On purpose exception");

                ...

                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                    
                outputProvider.PrintLine(ex.Message);
                transaction.Rollback();
                dbContext = new ATMDbContext();
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("On context recreation: ");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(dbContext.CardAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CardNumber == cardNumber).CardCash);
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }       
    }
}
```

I am using the following method for testing purposes:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var dbContext = new ATMDbContext();
    var atm = new ATMClient(dbContext);

    var account = dbContext.CardAccounts.Where(x => x.CardCash >= 10000).FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Before withdraw: ");
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine(account.CardNumber);
    Console.WriteLine(account.CardCash);
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine();

    atm.WithdrawMoney(account.CardNumber, account.CardPIN, 10000m);

    account = dbContext.CardAccounts.Where(x => x.CardNumber == account.CardNumber).FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("After withdraw: ");
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine(account.CardNumber);
    Console.WriteLine(account.CardCash);
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The final results I get:

```
Before withdraw:
-----------------------------------
0030972041
224027.53
-----------------------------------
On purpose exception

On context recreation: 
----------------------------
224027.53
----------------------------

After withdraw:
-----------------------------------
0030972041
214027.53
-----------------------------------
```

For some reason the "after withdraw" printing uses an incorrect context, even though i have recreated it in the Withdraw method. What can be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect context"?

Comment: I mean, it should either stay unchanged or be the recreated one, not the middle point. As you see, the balance of the card gets decremented and that is reflected while the recreation is not. I considered the possibility of reference issues by passing the context as a parameter and it actually turns out to be true.

Comment: I don't have any idea why the original context does not rollback the changes it is tracking. I guess this is how EF works for some reason. As to why your context "recreation" is not working as you expect I have explained why in my answer. When you pass reference type around the copy of the reference is passed. Easy way to think of the reference is as an address. The address is passed to the method. The address is say 5. You changed the value of the variable to 10 but the original 5 is still there in the original method's local variable.

Comment: At first, I wanted to test the EF context behaviour on a rollback situation and I got to the same exact conclusion(it just doesn't rollback for some reason). This led to further testing but I couldn't graps what i do wrong in the current situation and I knew I'm missing something tiny. Thank you for the clearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what behavior you are trying to achieve but I suspect that you expect the context in the local variable in the Main method to change because you passed it as an argument to the constructor. This is not how references work. When you pass a reference as an argument a copy of the reference is given to the method. If it is replaced by another reference the original variable is not changed. In the Main method you still use the object that you initialized on the first line.

If you want the method to be able to change the reference you should declare the parameter as "ref" but I doubt this is the best solution for whatever it is you want to achieve.

Comment: Totally. I knew I'm missing something small and stupid. Greatly appreciated!